# Liferay Portal don't send object from process phase to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, request, liferay, getattribute

i'm new in liferay, and now i'm learning Liferay with liferaycookbook. I have a problem with send object from porlet to jsp page
[here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/8ntv47y9586erm5/library.jar)'s my porlet,.In `LibraryPortlet.java` i have a function:

```
public void searchBooks(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    String searchTerm = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "searchTerm");

    if (Validator.isNotNull(searchTerm)) {
        try {
            List<LMSBook> lmsBooks = LMSBookLocalServiceUtil
                    .searchBooks(searchTerm);

            actionRequest.setAttribute("SEARCH_RESULT", lmsBooks);
            actionRequest.setAttribute("test", "sentence to test");
            actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage",
                    LibraryConstants.PAGE_LIST);

        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in file `list.jsp`, i have

```
List<LMSBook> booksTemp = (List<LMSBook>) request
        .getAttribute("SEARCH_RESULT");

List<LMSBook> books = Validator.isNotNull(booksTemp) ? ListUtil
        .copy(booksTemp) : LMSBookLocalServiceUtil.getLMSBooks(0,
        LMSBookLocalServiceUtil.getLMSBooksCount());
System.out.println("test: "+ request.getAttribute("test"));
```

in `list.jsp`, `booksTemp` is `null` because liferay can't send my object from `LibraryPortlet.java` to jsp, i try to send the string "sentence to test", but in console, it shows test: `null`

Anybody have had same problem, can you help me, please!

Comment: don't make statement like " liferay can't send my object from LibraryPortlet.java to jsp".could you please check your condition Validator.isNotNull(searchTerm) and check whether control is going inside or not

Comment: i don't understand why don't make statement that, can u explain for me.

Comment: Validator.isNotNull(searchTerm) return true, it means try catch block was performed, just object didn't send to jsp file.

Comment: "LibraryConstants.PAGE_LIST" please paste value of this

Comment: LibraryConstants.PAGE_LIST = /html/library/list.jsp. it's just a constants value. The problem is the code run well in my partner project, but with my project, it's wrong, i don't know why. we're learnt liferay together, i don't know it depends on whatever....

Comment: In the real, i just copy and paste the code in liferaycookbook, even that is the code in google code
subversion code in google here: https://code.google.com/p/lr-book/source/detail?r=23

Comment: Why are you using scriptlets?  Scriptlets are very bad practice and should be avoided if at all possible, in favor of JSTL/EL.  You can access the value easily from JSTL/EL like this:  <c:out value="${requestScope.test}" />

Answer (score 0):

You must first use the correct request to set your attribute. The problem is that in the LibraryPortlet, you are using a type of `PortletRequest` and the object in the JSP is a `HttpServletRequest`.

For your case, in `LibraryPortlet.java`, do the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);

request.setAttribute("SEARCH_RESULT", lmsBooks);
```

This also goes for any other attribute you are setting.